# Bane's age and his physique in The Dark Knight Rises

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

We know that

- The background story arc of "Lazarus Pit" takes place 30 years before the time of Batman Begins.
- The time difference between Batman Begins and The Dark Knight must be approximately 6 months to a year.
- Time difference between Dark Knight and The Dark Knight Rises is 8 years

> In a backstory, we are revealed that Bane was the one who helped Talia Al Ghul to escape the lazarus pit. We are not shown his face but according to his physique he should have been between 18 to 20.

And regarding to this calculation, Bane must be 55+

> 38 [Time of Dark Knight Trilogy story arc] + 18 [youngest possible age of bane at the time of backstory]..

Is this assumption true?

Comment: Where does the 30 years number come from?  I don't recall it stated in the film.

Comment: Almost stated everywhere, wikipedia IMDB it's kind of backstory info provided by emulators...

Comment: Checking both those sites, I'm not seeing this information.

Comment: Given the apparent age of the child actor involved, and the adult actor of the same character (being spoiler-careful here), thirty years is just about right.

Comment: On wikipedia, under cast section : Josh Pence and Liam Neeson both appear as Ra's al Ghul, leader of the League of Shadows; Pence plays a younger version of the character in scenes set thirty years before the events of Batman Begins

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable to assume he's in his 50's.  If Brad Pitt was 41 in Troy and Randy Couture was 46 when he came out of retirement with that level of physique it makes sense that Bane could be ten years older and still have the build of a heavy weight MMA fighter.

Comment: @Monty129 Plus he's a super-human right?

Comment: @Mooz not in the film universe he's not.  They removed the Venom aspect of his character from the comics, and instead his mask provides an analgesic gas that keeps him from being overwhelmed from the injuries he sustained in the prison sequence of his origin.  In the comics he is, his strength on Venom lets him at least lift 10 tons, possibly more.

Comment: Human Growth Hormone

Comment: Related: [Talia and Bane age problems?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8196/49)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This assumption is valid, but likely doesn't restrict him much. In the comics, Bane was enhanced by Venom, giving him superhuman strength and an indestructible quality. There's no mention of this in The Dark Knight Rises, but I would suppose that there's few alternative ways he could survive the injuries he sustained in the Pit. He is probably much older than he appears because of the Venom.

Comment: I think there is an indirect mention of it : A doctor in the pit says about an injury and his medicine created a lifelong effect..This must be the reason why bane is appearing almost 20 years younger than his age

Comment: I have to wonder, however, if the aforementioned medicine is Bane's Venom? If so, why aren't all those prisoners massively masculine?

Comment: I think Venom was effectively written out of the movie.  The assumption that Bane is 56 is reasonable, and given what we actually see of Bane - only part of his face and a shaved head - he could well be 56 who works out a _lot_.

Comment: @gobernador may be he must be the only one who is severely injured and needed such medicine...

Comment: @dlanod not only the face and shaved head, but his movement and his behavior is like the 35+ year old, instead of reflecting his real age.

Comment: I would assume his muscles and speed are more of a byproduct of his League of Shadows training. The movie made it seem like his respirator was more of a weakness than a strength.

Comment: I took his physique to also be of someone who is older.  Tom Hardy is muscular, but also toned.  Bane was not toned at all.  he had the body of a man who had muscle mass, but also fat (not excessive, but there was fat) as well.  Also, I felt it apparent that he so easily took on Batman (round 1) because of his League of Shadows training.

Comment: @Ryan: It's not a weakness so much as a result of a weakness. The respirator eliminates the pain he would experience otherwise. This means it both makes him less weak (by concealing the existing pain), and makes him stronger than normal (by concealing any externally inflicted pain). But, yes, when fighting him, it is technically a point of weakness, since by damaging the respirator, it would cease to conceal the pain from his past injury.

Answer (score 8):

How old is Bane?

- 1/18/78: roughly the date of Bruce Wayne's birth
- 1977-78: roughly the events of Ras' pregnant wife being put in the pit and the eventual birth of Talia
- 1984-88: around the time when Talia's mother was killed, Talia's climb out of the well, and the return assault from Ra's Al Ghul on those in the well who mauled the prisoner who saved Talia, the start of Bane.

  This says Talia was between 6-10 years old, roughly 8.
- 1986-1987: roughly the events of Bruce falling into the well, and the eventual deaths of his parents at the hands of Joe Chill, who was apprehended by police and incarcerated.
  This leaves Bruce at roughly age 8.
- 1986-2008: Sometime after Talia and Ra's rescue from the pit of what would become Bane, and before Ras took on Bruce as a student, Bane trained under Ras for some amount of time and was excommunicated for being a monster Ras' could not control or look upon, and Talia chose to go with him.
- 2000-2001: 14 years later, Bruce returns home from college to witness the hearing of Joe Chill due to his early release from prison in regards to incriminating information that was shared inside with former prisoner and mob boss, Carmine Falcone. Bruce's attempt to murder Chill is foiled at the last second when he is shot by one of Falcone's people. Bruce confronts Falcone and is easily subdued by his men, but Falcone's ego and insults inadvertently inspires Bruce to become Batman when he leaves Gotham to understand the criminal element and travel the world.
- 2001-2008: Bruce travels the world, masquerades as a criminal, learns crude ways of fighting and gets caught and thrown in jail during a heist. There he meets Ra's Al Ghul, who offers him a path, to train with the League of Shadows. The rest of Batman Begins plays out. Bruce is to be revealed to be 30 years old at his birthday party toward the final 30 minutes of the film.
- 2008-2016: Talia finds out at some point about Bruce's betrayal to the League and the death of her father at his hands. She and Bane formulate a very long con on Bruce as well as Batman, as well as fulfilling her father's plans for destroying Gotham.
- 07/18/08: 6 months after the events at the end of Batman Begins, the events of The Dark Knight take place, establishing a definitive year of when the events actually take place. Proof is on the security photo Gordon shows Batman of the Joker robbing the bank at the start of the movie. Bruce is still 30.
- 7-11/16: Bruce has retired for roughly 8 years as Batman due to the lie he and Gordon made up about Dent and the circumstances surrounding his death and the string of murders he committed; Batman is wanted for murder while Harvey Dent is martyred as the city's real hero.  Bane and Talia enact their plan on Bruce. Eventually, Bruce is defeated by Bane and placed in the well for around 3 months before his escape. When he returns to Gotham for his rematch with Bane, it is snowing in Gotham which places the month around mid October to November.

Bruce is 38 years old.

Talia, at the time if her death, was 37-38 like Bruce.

Bane must have been at least 18-25 like Bruce was when Ras' rescued him from prison, which is what Ras' did for Bruce as well. Both also became members and former members of the League of Shadows. Bruce and Talia also lost one or both parents as a child; Talia only knowing one parent at a time but never together.

So Bane, say around 22, got messed up protecting 8 year old Talia al Ghul in 1986-1987. If the movie takes place in 2016 (as proved in the timeline), that's 30 years later, which means:

Bane has to be between 50-55.

CASE CLOSED.

Answer (score 0):

remember bruce is pushing 39 - 40 yrs of age when he gets to bane. in begins he is celebrating his 30th birthday when he fights ras. 31 possibly 32 when he fights the joker and two-face. so i would assume most of his villains are atleast his age or older by a few years.

Answer (score 0):

In the comics it's shown he spent 25-30 years in the pit. Afterwards he came to Gotham so my guess is he is around 60 something. Talia is around 38 years old and Bruce is the same

Plus he was seen in movie as a full adult saving Talia as a child. By the looks he was around 30 years old (a mature man) .and adding the age of Talia 38 - 8  =30 -- that means Bane is around 60 yrs old. With the super steroids venom he used he hasn't aged a bit.